# How to autofill blank cells in a column based on other column values in excel?

Tags: excel, data-analysis, autofill

I have an excel sheet with location data including place, id, latitude and longitude values.There are multiple rows for each combination of latitude and longitude values in which some are filled with place names and some are blank. I have to fill the blank cells in place column based on corresponding latitude and longitude combinations. Since there are more than 100 distinct places, i am trying to find a way to auto fill the blankcells. Is there a way to automate the task?

I tried to use if condition, but there are lots of places to fill and it is impossible to write the formula manually.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you provide some sample data and expected output it is much easier to help you - best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).